# Frontend styling has disappeared, and I can't get it back

Tags: magento2, css, frontend, less-css, styles

*Disclaimer: I'm new to **Magento 2 development** as of **Nov 2018**, and new to development generally as of mid-2017.  So I'm new to asking development-help questions too.  Most of the time I can figure it out on my own.  Please forgive me for anything I do that is something I should know not to do.*

**My problem:**
All styling is gone from my frontend (admin is fine).

**When the problem started:**
When I was trying to add a custom font via an '_extend.less' file.  (Creating this file and using it to make changes was the method that was being used in a tutorial I was following to make custom styling changes.)

(I have Magento set to Developer Mode.)

I have set everything back to the way it was before trying to add the custom font (as best I can tell), but the problem still remains.  Around the time I was trying to add the custom font, I remember using the command `cache:disable`, and maybe this messed something up?  I've since used `cache:enable`, but the CLI responds with `There is nothing to change in cache status`.

I have searched online over the course of 3 days for a total of around 10 hours for a solution.  Just so you know I've really tried to figure this out on my own, the following are some things I have tried many (many!) times, and in many variations as to their order and combination (I'm pretty sure new developers do this a lot!):

- `indexer:reindex`
- `cache:clean`
- `setup:upgrade`
- `setup:static-content:deploy -f`
- `deploy:mode:set production`

  (The idea here was apparently setting it to Production Mode would clear things in a certain way, and then I was supposed to set it back to Developer Mode, and this would fix the problem. But I get an error part way through setting it to Production Mode when it tries to deploy static content, and it shows a message in bright red: `Command returned non-zero exit code`.  Plus above that there's a line that reads: `Something went wrong while deploying static content. See the error log for details.`  Is the error file it's talking about in 'var > log'?  Because all the files in there have a 'Date modified' showing 8 days ago, which is way before this problem started. What log file is this referring to?)
- using the 'Flush Static Files Cache' button (In Admin: System > Cache Management)
- using the 'Flush JavaScript/CSS Cache' button (In Admin: System > Cache Management)
- using the bright orange 'Flush Magento Cache' button (In Admin: System > Cache Management)
- setting directory and file permissions (pretty much to 777 every time)
- `rm -rf view_preprocessed/*`
- `rm -rf static/*`
- `rm -rf var/{cache,di,generation,page_cache,view_preprocessed}`
- and I couldn't begin to tell you how many times I've hit 'Shift+F5' to refresh the storefront page

'No styling' seems like such a simple issue, but I can't figure this one out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I'm on Apache, all served from Google Cloud Platform (static IP), Bitnami stack.

*Edit: screenshots added*

[image: browser view - no styling issue]

[image: console view - no styling issue]

Comment: Hi, please attach a screenshot of the front end with console logs. Are you on Apache or Nginx?

Comment: Kudos for a well written and well researched question...

Answer (score 1):

Please check in your frontend store language. If frontend store language is different then you need to setup:static-content:deploy -f {lanug_code}.

Like, If your frontend store in Germany then run below command.

> setup:upgrade 
> setup:static-content:deploy -f de_DE en_US 
> cache:clean 
> Give full permission to var/ and pub/ folder
>
> de_DE use for frontend store and en_US for backend side.

I hope so it's work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm using 'en_US' only.  I've never enabled any other languages.

Answer (score 0):

Check followings (Suppose you are in developer mode),

- Make sure .htaccess file is present under pub/static folder with correct contents. https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/pub/static/.htaccess
- Make sure apache mod_rewrite is installed and enabled
- Make sure .htaccess can alter
- Delete caches. `rm -rf var/cache var/page_cache generated var/generation var/view_processed`
- Restart varnish if exists

To troubleshoot the static content deployment issue

- Try to compile blank theme. `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -t Magento/blank`

Comment: .htaccess is present (permissions are 777), and has the same content as the one you linked to... apart from something about 'moxieplayer' in the linked one which I've ignored. I tried to delete caches as you suggested, but get 'Permission denied' for all files even though permissions are 777 recursively. I used `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart` for both apache and varnish. I get `varnish started at port 80` and `httpd started at port 81`(apache). Should the ports match? Compiled blank theme... still getting ''static content' error.  In httpd.conf, changed  AllowOverride to All from None

Comment: Seems you have a file permission issue. Try running static content deploy as root user. `sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -t Magento/blank
` The ports shouldn't be the same. Hope you have updated the varnish vcl.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I came up with a **solution:  start a new custom theme**.

No, that's not the solution I was hoping for.  But sometimes the best thing to do is abandon something if it's not working and start over.  In my case, fortunately, I wasn't too far along with the first theme, and it didn't take long to get back to where I left off.  So I can confirm everything behind the scenes is still working fine.  There's just something with what I was doing before that broke, and I couldn't fix it.  I don't like that, because if whatever caused the problem happens again, I'm right back at the same place again.  I really don't want a recurring solution of 'start over' every time.  But I feel I spent enough time trying to figure it out, so let's just move forward, and cross that [broken] bridge if we come to it again.

Thanks to everyone for taking your time to try to help.